# VSCode blank screen on 1.19.0 update

Tags: visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.19.0
- OS Version: Windows 10 1709 (16299.125)
- Reproduces without extensions: Yes

There is no way to open VSCode after 1.19.0 update installed. It always launches blank screen and prints 2 error messages in debug console.

```
index.js:5 TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of null
    at file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:2920:762
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at e.setCustomTokenColors (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:2920:735)
    at new e (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:2927:679)
    at t.create (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:90:103)
    at e._createInstance (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:1209:289)
    at e.createInstance (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:1208:560)
    at e.initServiceCollection (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4516:741)
    at e.createContents (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4511:118)
    at e.open (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4518:113)
onError @ index.js:5
```

I tried to reinstall vscode or launch it without extensions - same result.

**What's more**, I got the same issue on Linux virtual machine:

- VSCode Version: 1.19.0
- OS Version: Ubuntu 17.10 x64

  index.js:41 TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of null
      at file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:2920:762
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at e.setCustomTokenColors (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:2920:735)
      at new e (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:2927:679)
      at t.create (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:90:103)
      at e._createInstance (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:1209:289)
      at e.createInstance (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:1208:560)
      at e.initServiceCollection (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4516:741)
      at e.createContents (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4511:118)
      at e.open (file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4518:113)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the same issue as [#40339](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40339), which has already been fixed on VSCode's master branch. The issue's milestone (November Recovery 2017) indicates that it will be part of a 1.19.1 patch release.

For now, it looks like you can work around the issue by setting `editor.tokenColorCustomization` to `{}` ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40308#issuecomment-352229028)):

> Can you check if you have `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` set to `null` in your settings file (you can find it at ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json). If yes, then set it to `{}` instead and then try opening VS Code.